# Is vfio-pci a userspace driver for all pci devices?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, driver, linux-device-driver, vfio

I know that vfio can expose interrupt, DMA and pci I/O to userspace. I read that if someone want to take advantage of vfio for pci devices, he has to unbind the original driver and bind to vfio-pci driver. So my question is, is vfio-pci a userspace driver for all pci devices? Because in my understanding, vfio just offers some basic interfaces. Or, if I need a driver for a new pci device, should I just use vfio-pci driver or use interfaces it offers to write a new driver?

Comment: vfio-pci is kernel space driver that is exposing PCI device interfaces to userspace - it is primarily used to expose PCI devices to virtual machines. You can bind it to any PCI device, but have to write userspace driver for such device using vfio driver interfaces.